# Faster downloading of a file

Tags: python, performance, python-2.7

I am downloading an XML file over the internet using requests module and writing to the file in chunks. The code for the above looks like

```
r = requests.get(xml_url+version, stream=True)
with open('test.xml', 'wb') as f:
    for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=1024): 
        if chunk:
            f.write(chunk)
```

The file size can vary from anywhere between a few KBs to about 150 MBs. Note that the file needs to be strictly in order and therefore, using multithreading for asynchronous writes is not an option.

Can anyone please help me with how to increase the speed of writing to the file as when the file size reaches a hundred MBs, it takes a lot of time for downloading the file and becomes quite expensive.

Comment: How do you know it's your code and not your internet connection?

Comment: @Martin Konecny I have a 16Mbps internet connection which on speed test provides practical speed of almost 14Mbps. So I believe that it should take a maximum of 90 seconds to retrieve 100MB of data.

Comment: Have you tried a larger chunk size, eg 64k?

Comment: I have been trying with 1k and 2k sizes only... I'll look into that!

Comment: @PM2Ring larger chunk sizes did help but on a 5MB file, the max difference I've encoountered is 0.5 seconds. Any other suggestion?

Comment: Is it faster if you download it using a Web browser? If that's the case, it _could_ be that DL'ing it via your Python script is slow due to the server limiting the DL speed because it doesn't like bots. You _might_ be able to get around that by spoofing a browser with an appropriate UserAgent identifier.

Comment: I tried downloading the large 100MB file using browser and the postman extension of chrome. Postman crashed and chrome wasn't any better than postman. So I'm unable to comment on that. Although I can try to spoof a web browser to increase the speed. Can you please tell me about which UserAgent identifiers I can use?